# Bootstrap 3 side by side two 50% width divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to accomplish this for the last two days. Plz somebody help. I am trying to divide the page in half. The left side 100% height and the right side just scroll with more content. Why is the right side collapsing on top of the left side? How to solve this riddle in Bootstrap 3? Here is my code:

```
<section id="main-body" class="container-fixed main-body">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 left-side-home-outer">
                Left Side Content
           </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 right-side-home">
                Right Side Content
            </div>
        </div>
</section>

.left-side-home-outer {
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
font-family: "Roboto";
font-weight: 800;
}

.right-side-home-outer {

border: 1px solid blue;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
overflow: auto;
font-family: "Roboto";
font-weight: 800;
}
```

And if possible, if I want to add a footer fixed to the bottom of the left side, what would be the CSS?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: why width 50% in right-side-home-outer?

Comment: and why fixed on left-side-home-outer, also your html class is "right-side-home".. your css displays ".right-side-home-outer"

Comment: @Maulzal I was actually working on a more complex page and just stripped off the inner div, that's why the class names doesn't add up. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for `position: fixed`.. that is what causing overlapping of content.

Also `width:50%` is also redundant..as it already a `col-md-6`..a 50% width column.

```
<section id="main-body" class="container-fixed main-body">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 left-side-home-outer">
                Left Side Content
           </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 right-side-home">
                Right Side Content
            </div>
        </div>
</section>

.left-side-home-outer {
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 100%;
font-family: "Roboto";
font-weight: 800;
}

.right-side-home-outer {

border: 1px solid blue;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
font-family: "Roboto";
font-weight: 800;
}
```

Comment: Thanks much for the replies but is it my browser? The divs are not taking 100% height at all. It's collapsing to the content height. That's the whole problem I was stuck to actually. I went forward and made a pen with one of the solutions, of @Mary Kelly. Here it is:
http://codepen.io/rpmcmurphy/pen/ZWLoBP

Comment: No, it is not your browser...it is how it is suppose to be... I'll update the answer if you want `height:100%`...

Comment: http://codepen.io/rpmcmurphy/pen/mPRLzq
Here is a fork of your codepen link. I changed the left position to fixed and added longer contents to the right column to overflow.
Can the left column be fixed like this and the right column scroll without the border showing through the extra content as seen in the fork?
My ultimate purpose is to have the left column always stay fixed and right column scroll. The left side will work as a fixed side menu with 100% height. And in Bootstrap col-md-* actually please. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have fixed positioning, in fact, you shouldn't.  Also, you don't need the 50% width in your classes.   Here, try this.... I couldn't get it to respond in a fiddle, but it worked in a local file I ran (is what is copied below).

```
<style>
.left-side-home-outer {
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 100%;
font-family: "Roboto";
font-weight: 800;
}

.right-side-home-outer {

border: 1px solid blue;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
font-family: "Roboto";
font-weight: 800;
}

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section id="main-body" class="container-fixed main-body">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 left-side-home-outer">
                Left Side Content
           </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 right-side-home-outer">
                Right Side Content
            </div>
        </div>
</section>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```